# Trouble installing Linux headers on Kali

Tags: windows-7, linux, kali-linux

I need to install headers and build-essentials in order to install wifi drivers. So, I can't install them from terminal because I don't have internet access from Linux.
I am dual booting Kali and Windows 7. My Wifi adapter is a Netgear AC1200. It works on the Windows OS, but not Kali. I need to install a driver to get  it to work. What would be the easiest way that you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect computer via ethernet to Netgear AC1200, then install (assuming your PC has ethernet, and the ethernet drivers are not disabled in the stock kernel).
2. Download Kali `.deb` packages in Windows, copy to Linux partitions, install from packages using `dpkg -i` etc.